# How to print or save Symbian Device Logs to File

Tags: logging, symbian

Can any One Show me How to get the Symbian device Logs and save them to file, Like Logcat Device log in android.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What logs? There are not any logs created on normal device

Comment: device logs like which will print on carbide c++ IDE , as Emulator out put console.

Answer (score 0):

Real device does not equal Emulator. There are no logs of loading DLL files or processes in phone. If you want to log something then you have to do it yourself in your application.